# Cannot get handle of process

Tags: c++, winapi

**SOLVED: Look at the last post by me. This is probably Windows XP and previous versions problem with the rights needed for GetProcessId function.**

There are no build errors. GetProcessId still returns 0. I can't solve this problem.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h> //For EnumProcessModules.
#include <tlhelp32.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

HANDLE GetHandleByName( string str )
{
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL );

    if( Process32First( snapshot, &entry ) == TRUE )
    {
        while( Process32Next( snapshot, &entry ) == TRUE )
        {
            WCHAR* wchrstr = ( WCHAR * )malloc( 128 );
            mbstowcs ( wchrstr, str.c_str(), 128 );
            if( wcscmp( reinterpret_cast< const wchar_t * >( entry.szExeFile ), wchrstr ) == 0 )
            {
                hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID );
            }
            free( wchrstr );
         }
    }

    CloseHandle( snapshot );
    return hProcess;
}



void main()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetHandleByName( "System" );

    cout << GetProcessId( hProcess );
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: There may not be build errors, but you're never checking for run-time errors in your code. API functions calls like `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` and `OpenProcess()` can *and sometimes will* fail at runtime, and your code should be ready to handle exceptional situations. See [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx).

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE and before that ERROR_INVALID_SEGMENT_NUMBER

Comment: It doesn't sound like you use GetLastError() correctly.  The most likely error code is 5.  You are asking for too much access, tone down PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS to the minimum you need to get the job done.  Avoid PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, that's a high privilege.

Comment: Change `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` to `PROCESS_TERMINATE`.

Comment: It didn't help. This program: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx works just fine for all processes. I want to make something like that.

Comment: I tested on the other processes and same problem.

Comment: Let's take a step back. Why do you need to create a handle to another process? You should pass the process handle as part of the IPC rather than making the recipient try to figure it out, particularly since the recipient may not have sufficient access to create a new handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the real problem was ladies and gentelmen: **GetProcessId( HANDLE process )** from windows.h which still returned 0 as the result. I have replaced the function with:

EDIT: There is also second way to fix the problem, using AdjustTokenPrivileges thanks that we can use PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS so the original **GetProcessId** will work without using the function below which simply creates remote thread.

```
DWORD WINAPI GetProcessIDbyProcessHandle(HANDLE hProcess)
{
    if (hProcess == NULL)    return 0xffffffff;
    PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)
        GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Kernel32")), "GetCurrentProcessId");
    if (lpStartAddress == NULL) return 0xffffffff;
    // We do not know, whether process handle already has required access rights;

    // thus we have to duplicate it
    HANDLE hProcessAccAdj;
    BOOL bRes = DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), 
                                hProcess, GetCurrentProcess(), &hProcessAccAdj, 
                                PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD|
                                PROCESS_VM_OPERATION|PROCESS_VM_WRITE, 
                                FALSE, 0);
    if (!bRes || hProcessAccAdj == NULL)
    {
        UINT unError = GetLastError();
        return 0xffffffff;
    }
    // Create a remote thread; as its starting address 

    // we specify GetCurrentProcessId() address,
    // which is the same for all processes. Note that GetCurrentProcessId() has no input
    // parameters, and we don't care about our thread stack cleanup,
    // as it will be destroyed right after this call

    DWORD dwThreadID;
    HANDLE hRemoteThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcessAccAdj, NULL, 
        0, lpStartAddress, 0, 0, &dwThreadID);
    CloseHandle(hProcessAccAdj);
    if (hRemoteThread == NULL) return 0xffffffff;
    // Wait until process ID is obtained

    // (replace INFINITE value below to a smaller value to avoid deadlocks);
    // then get the thread exit code, which is a value returned by GetCurrentProcessId()
    // in the context of the remote process
    WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
    DWORD dwExitCode;
    if (GetExitCodeThread(hRemoteThread, &dwExitCode) == 0)    dwExitCode = 0xffffffff;
    CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
    return dwExitCode;
}
```

Comment: The kind reserved for "_so, wait... instead of correctly using the API to query the process ID of a process given a `HANDLE` to it, you instead attempt to open the process requesting highly elevated privileges, *then* attempt to inject a thread into it, which will call `GetCurrentProcessId` on your behalf only to *then* exit so that you *then* retrieve the process ID using the thread exit code?_" This "solution" is equivalent to breaking into a neighbor's house while they aren't there, to rifle through their papers because want to know his last name but don't want to ask directly.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, are you trying to get the `System` process or the `[System Process]` virtual process? Either way, your code has a few issues that must be addressed.

If you're trying for just `System` then your code would work with only minor tweaks. If what you really want is `[System Process]` then you're out of luck.

First of all, you do no error checking. Perhaps `CreateToohelp32Snapshot` failed and you're using an invalid handle in your `Process32First` call. Secondly, you call `Process32First` and then *immediately* call `Process32Next` without looking at the process that `Process32First` returned. In other words, you're always skipping the first process returned. Coincidentally, guess which process is the first process returned? It's the virtual `[System Process]`.

So let's try a function that enumerates all processes and does it correctly:

```
void EnumAllProcesses(BOOL bTryToOpen = FALSE,
                      DWORD dwAccess = PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL );

    if( snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Unable to create a ToolHelp32 snapshot (%08X)\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if( Process32First( snapshot, &entry ) == TRUE )
    {
        do
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Process: %s (%u)\n"), entry.szExeFile, entry.th32ProcessID);

            if(bTryToOpen)
            {
                HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( dwAccess,
                                               FALSE, 
                                               entry.th32ProcessID );

                _tprintf(_T("    hProcess = %p (%08X)\n"), hProcess, GetLastError());

                if(hProcess != NULL)
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
            }
        } while( Process32Next( snapshot, &entry ) == TRUE );        
    }

    CloseHandle( snapshot );
}
```

But even with this new code you will have issues if you want to open `[System Process]`. The reason is that `OpenProcess` will fail with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when you specify the process ID of this process (which happens to always be zero). This is **documented** behavior. Look at the MSDN page on [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and specifically at the `dwProcessId` argument explanation:

> If the specified process is the System Process (0x00000000), the
>   function fails and the last error code is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. If
>   the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS
>   processes, this function fails and the last error code is
>   `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` because their access restrictions prevent
>   user-level code from opening them.

Here's a snapshot of the output of this code on my system, running as non-admin:

```
Process: [System Process] (0)
    hProcess = 00000000 (00000057) 
Process: System (4)
    hProcess = 00000000 (00000005)
Process: smss.exe (324)
    hProcess = 00000000 (00000005)
Process: csrss.exe (492)
    hProcess = 00000000 (00000005)
Process: wininit.exe (568)
    hProcess = 00000000 (00000005)
```

Notice that the error when trying to open `[System Process]` (with PID 0) the error is, correctly, "invalid parameter". When trying to open `System` (with PID 4) the error is 5 - which translates to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. This is what I'd expect since I ask for **full access** and I'm not running as admin. So I try running this as admin. Yet the results won't change. Hmm... what could be the problem?

Well, it might be that you are asking for `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` to processes that do not allow you to ask for that much access even if you're an admin. Just because you are the owner of ancyBank doesn't mean you can walk into a branch and demand that the manager just open other people's safety deposit boxes... So how about you try asking for **LESS** access. How about `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` instead?

Now, the evidence (as you relay it) suggests that your call to `CreatToolHelp32Snapshot` fails, and the loop is never entered or that you are running as non-admin and asking for information on a process which you don't have access to. But I have no faith that you are accurately relaying what's happening and you are not helping us help you.

Comment: I still haven't got the handle. The problem occurs when comparing the strings. 

**if( wcscmp( reinterpret_cast< const wchar_t * >( entry.szExeFile ), wchrstr ) == 0 )**

OpenProcess wasn't even called so you can't just say that it is the problem.

Comment: If that's not called, the problem would **SEEM** to be that your `CreateToolHelp32Snapshot` fails. Do you even know what error checking is? Do you do it?

Comment: It fails when trying to open every process.

Comment: Fails how? What's the error? If you go to the emergency room, you don't scream "**I DON'T WORK!**". You say "Well, I have chest pains and feel radiating pain in my arm." And if the doctor asks you a quesion, you **answer** it.

Comment: @matsuoka: If you are not compiling for Unicode, the way you are using `reinterpret_cast` is a bug, and if you are compiling for Unicode then your use of it is redundant. Either way, it is wrong in this context so get rid of it completely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: So how can I compare the strings then? I thought so that reinterpret_cast is a problem.

Comment: @matsuoka `_tcsicmp(_T("System"), entry.szExeFile) == 0) { ... }`. If you want to something more generic via the TCHAR macros, don't pass a `std::string` into the function - pass a `LPCTSTR` instead and compile.

Answer (score 2):

The OS will not allow you to open the system process. It would also be pretty useless as it's not a usual process with modules etc.

```
dwProcessId [in]
The identifier of the local process to be opened.
```

`If the specified process is the System Process (0x00000000), the function fails and the last error code is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER. If the specified process is the Idle process or one of the CSRSS processes, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED because their access restrictions prevent user-level code from opening them.`

Also you need higher privileges to open another process. You can do this by executing the program as administrator, [require an administrator from the UAC manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) or disabling UAC to test such applications.

`To open a handle to another local process and obtain full access rights, you must enable the SeDebugPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Changing Privileges in a Token.`

On my UAC disabled system the program works fine, when I only change the process name to something that can be opened.

Comment: You are wrong. Look at this program: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx It can open every process. I can adjust token privileges but I need other way. Anyway problem persists in **if( wcscmp( reinterpret_cast< const wchar_t * >( entry.szExeFile ), wchrstr ) == 0 )** because if I try to output something in body of this condition just nothing.

Comment: @matsuoka He's not wrong. You **CANNOT** open the System Process, since it has a PID of 0 and `OpenProcess` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` if you specify a process ID of 0.

Comment: I tried with any other process. Not only "System" which is not a real process. Just like I wrote in the previous comment the problem persists in condition.**OpenProcess isn't even called**...

Comment: @matsuoka I downloaded the program and could not find it opening the system process. As I wrote your program works without modifications with another process for me. Try to run it as administrator.

Comment: I dont have to run it as administrator while using winxp. And it **doesn't work for every process**.

Comment: @matsuoka I give up - you come here asking for help and you **insist** on not listening to what we tell you.

Comment: Tell me why my program works for him with other processes, but for me it just fails everywhere?

Comment: @matsuoka perhaps if you run the second version of `EnumAllProcesses` in my answer thusly: `EnumAllProcesses(TRUE)` you'd find out. But that would be too easy... wouldn't it?